# Persisting EnumSet in Postgresql with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, enums, enumset

[Effective Java](http://uet.vnu.edu.vn/~chauttm/e-books/java/Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.3000th.Release.pdf), Item 32, states Use EnumSet instead of bit fields. I also found [this nice tutorial](http://eddmann.com/posts/using-bit-flags-and-enumsets-in-java/) on the topic. This book has been around for a while, so why don't I find any posts on **how to persist an EnumSet with Hibernate?** Well, I actually found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418786/mapping-enumset-in-hibernate), and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402869/hibernate-how-to-map-an-enumset), but they are both quite old, point to the same and much older solution, which unfortunately did not help me, perhaps because of my lack of deeper hibernate knowledge? Here is an abstract of my code:

```
public class MyThing {
    public enum MyOptions {
        FLAG1, FLAG2
    }

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "options")
    private EnumSet<MyOptions> options;

    // [other fields, getters, setters etc]
}
```

I've tried other annotations like

```
@ElementCollection
```

with and without `(targetClass = MyOptions.class)`

and

```
@JoinTable(name = "my_options",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
```

and also

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "options")
```

but with no luck.

Preferably, I'd store the information in a new column of the `my_thing` table, but I could also live with a separate table for the enums, if required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "my_options", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "mything_id"))
@Column(name = "option")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Set<MyOptions> options;
```

With this configuration, you need a database table named `my_options` with columns `option` and `mything_id` which targets `MyThing` table.

Comment: I would like to add that when I declare
`@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) private EnumSet<MyOptions> regions;`

I get `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements:`

so I had to modify my getter to get an instance of EnumSet<MyOptions> safely by doing this:

`public EnumSet<Region> getRegions() {`
`     return EnumSet.copyOf(regions);`
`    }`